# PyCharm recognize a module but do not import it

Tags: python, module, pycharm, pydrive

I try to import the `PyDrive` module in my `PyCharm` project : `from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth`.
I tried different things :

- Installing it directly from the project interpreter
- Download it with a pip command and import it with the path for the poject interpreter
- The same thing in Linux

Nothing works. Each time PyCharm recognize the module and even sugest the auto-completion, but when I run the project it keeps saying `ImportError: No module named pydrive.auth`

Any suggestion ?

EDIT : When I put directly the pydrive folder in my repository, and this time : `ImportError: No module named httplib2` from the first import of PyDrive.
My path is correct and httplib2 is again in my PyCharm project

Comment: On project interpreter, did you toggle the option "Install to user's site packages directory"?

Comment: At first no, but then I tried with this option. Nothing changed

Comment: can you run "from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth" on python terminal, outside of pycharm?

Comment: Yes it works, I can launch a webPage using pydrive without PyCharm

Comment: Do you have different versions of python on the machine? is it possible that what you run locally is not the version used by the PyCharm interpreter? Try python --version and compare it to the interpreter...

Comment: Python 2.7.6, same as PyCharm..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After noticing that the module is already installed, both by pip and by the project interpreter, and nothing worked, this what did the trick (finaly!):

1. make sure the module is indeed installed:

   sudo pip{2\3} install --upgrade httplib2
2. locate the module on your computer:

   find / | grep httplib2

you will need to reach the place in which pip is installing the module, the path would probably look like this:

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages

3. get into the path specified there, search for the module and copy all the relevant files and folders into your local pycharm project environment. this will be a directory with a path like this:

   /home/your_user/.virtualenvs/project_name/lib/python2.7

this is it. note however you may need to do this multiple times, since each module may have a dependencies...

good  luck!